# UILongPressGestureRecognizer coordinates of press

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

I am using UILongPressGestureRecogniser on a UIImageView in this way:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPress:)];
    [ImageViewPhotoCard addGestureRecognizer:longPress];


- (void)longPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)gesture {
if ( gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded ) {

    //NSString *key = [array objectAtIndex:i];

    UIButton* ButtonNote = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    ButtonNote.frame = CGRectMake(100, 200, 80, 80); // position in the parent view and set the size of the button

    [ButtonNote addTarget:self action:@selector(OpenNote:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    ButtonNote.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    UIImage* btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"purple_circle.png"];
    [ButtonNote setBackgroundImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [self.ViewA addSubview:ButtonNote];

    [ArrayNotes addObject:ButtonNote];

    [ButtonNote setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [ButtonNote setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
}
```

How is it possible to get the x and y coordinates of the point where the user has pressed?

Answer (score 4):

`CGPoint location = [gesture locationInView:self.view];`

Is probably what you are looking for. This gives you a CGPoint of the touched point, according to the `self.view` coordinates